# Which methods in PropertyProvider are used during code generation?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have implemented a UITestPropertyProvider for my custom control following the steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh552522.aspx

When I use the Coded UI Test Builder I can see my custom properties on my custom controls and I can record steps that interact with the control and the code generates and playback works fine. But when I try to add an assert on *any* property--not just the custom properties added through PropertyProvider--when try to generate code for that I get an error that says "Cannot add the same member twice to a SerializationInfo object."

When I remove my custom property provider I can still record and playback clicks and stuff and I can assert on any property, but I cannot access my custom properties.

There's got to be something wrong with my PropertyProvider but I don't know what. Which methods of the PropertyProvider are being used during code generation?

Comment: Congratulations on following that article.  Exposing custom controls to Coded UI is a real pain in my opinion.  Have you tried renaming your members?  Somewhere in the depths, there could be a member with the same name as a custom member you've implemented.  A bit of a guess.

Comment: I figured out what is causing it. In that article it says to put the control name and the custom properties you want in a semicolon delimited string. I did that. But I have multiple control types that show up as simply "Text" in the uiTestControl.ControlType property. So I'm trying to access the description to get the actual control name, and it's failing because of the line that casts uiTestControl.NativeElement to an Object array.